# Расширить память корневого раздела linux

Tags: linux, память, gparted, fstab

Много читал про то как это сделать, но у меня немного отличается проблема от тех, что я находил в гугле.

У меня есть два раздела `sda6` и `sda7`.

`sda6` это корневой раздел `/`. Мне требуется его увеличить, за счет уменьшения размера `sda7`. Но `sda7` я могу уменьшать только с левой стороны, и при этом будет меняться его UUID. И так как у него меняется UUID, то моя операционка не сможет его распознать и загрузиться.
Я читал, что можно сделать магию в файле `fstab`, но ничего не понял, так как было написано для продвинутых, ну а я же пока не очень разбираюсь во всём этом.

Как мне правильно расширить диск `sda6` за счет уменьшения `sda7`, при этом используя gparted LiveCD?

Comment: Есть [такая прога](https://www.partitionwizard.com/), поищите аналоги, если нет возможности использовать на вашей системе

Comment: эта программа для windows

Comment: я всё могу сделать через gparted, но моя проблема в другом

Comment: Я к тому, что эта программа делаёт всё из коробки без лишних заморочек. Хочешь слева обрезай, хочешь справа, всё автоматически. Можно и fdisk-ом сделать всё, безусловно, но тогда надо думать, чтобы случайно не кирпичнуть диск

Comment: Если я зайду через винду и обрежу диск через эту программу, то он сам поменяет UUID в файле fstab?

Comment: При изменении размера ни UUID, ни PARTUUID меняться не должны. Непонятно, что такое странное вы делаете, что у вас UUID меняется

Comment: @andreymal При изменении памяти с левой стороны, меняется UUID

Comment: Нет, линукс файлы с винды она не поменяет. Я вообще вручную его редактировал 1 раз при установке системы, при расширении не надо его трогать

Comment: Может вам в 1 раздел всё слить, чтоб не двигать туда-обратно

Comment: Это странно, что замену одного UUID на другой в текстовом файле вы воспринимаете как магию.

Comment: Ну как бы вообщето странно что ещё есть конфигурации, в которых винт бьётся более чем на два раздела. Сейчас актуально наоборот, объединение дисков в одно хранилище (raid, btrfs, ceph, etc)... Лично я если и делаю на диске ещё один раздел, то только для swap. Две ОС если нужно, то предпочту установить каждую на свой диск.